# how to add cordova\phonegap functionality in Ionic Framework Project

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic Framework (ionic own generator). Now some of the functionality (e.g., *local notification, or taking picture from mobile camera*) i want to add in my app. I have this folder structure in my Project
root

hooks

node_modules

platform (android included)

scss

www

some files etc.,**

now how can i add functionality into my project. I know that cordova\phoneGap provide these kind of functionality but how to add that and how can i use those plugin in my controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngCordova. http://ngcordova.com/

local notification

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaLocalNotification) {

  $scope.addNotification = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
      id: 'some_notification_id'
      // parameter documentation:
      // https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#further-informations-1
    }).then(function () {
      console.log('callback for adding background notification');
    });
  };

  $scope.cancelNotification = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.cancel('some_notification_id').then(function () {
      console.log('callback for cancellation background notification');
    });
  };

  $scope.cancelAllNotification = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.cancelAll().then(function () {
      console.log('callback for canceling all background notifications');
    });
  };

  $scope.checkIfIsScheduled = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.isScheduled('some_notification_id').then(function (isScheduled) {
      console.log(isScheduled);
    });
  };

  $scope.getNotificationIds = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.getScheduledIds().then(function (scheduledIds) {
      console.log(scheduledIds);
    });
  };

  $scope.checkIfIsTriggered = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.isTriggered('some_notification_id').then(function (isTriggered) {
      console.log(isTriggered);
    });
  };

  $scope.getTriggeredIds = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.getTriggeredIds().then(function (triggeredIds) {
      console.log(triggeredIds);
    });
  };

  $scope.notificationDefaults = $cordovaLocalNotification.getDefaults();

  $scope.setDefaultOptions = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.setDefaults({ autoCancel: true });
  };

  // event callbacks events `onadd`, `ontrigger`, `onclick` and `oncancel`
  // can be assigned like this:
  $cordovaLocalNotification.onadd = function (id, state, json) {};

});
```

camera

```
module.controller('PictureCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  var options = {
    quality : 75,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 100,
    targetHeight: 100,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
    // Success! Image data is here
  }, function(err) {
    // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  });

});
```

Comment: And don't forget to add the cordova plugin using the CLI command : `cordova plugin add ...`

Answer (score 0):

Using ngCordova is optional but it's good to keep you application organized as it's providing service or directive through Angular DI(dependency injection).

For beginner they should know that using Cordova plugin in plain vanilla is the starting point to understand the usage of native functionality for the platform either IOS or Android. Please check this site http://www.plugreg.com/ to check for Cordova plugins available.